# Tcpdf generating table in examples directory but in no other

Tags: tcpdf

So I downloaded tcpdf... read and went through the examples, all works fine.

I then copied the tables example to another directory, made sure all included file paths were changed so all files were successfully included.

but it won't generate any tables or lists via writeHtml()! what is going on?

EDIT: I copied the exact same file in the exact same examples directory but with a different name, and this makes it not display any tables...

Comment: Try posting the code here, also when you say it won't generate any tables, what does it generate? Just an empty space?

Comment: Just empty space, yes, as for code, it's exactly the same as example 6, but with a different filename: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/?source=navbar

Comment: When you use the same filename, does it work? I mean the filename of the original example

Comment: No, I don't understand why, renamed the original file to example_006-old.php, copied the EXACT code in the working file and created a new file called example_006.php and it doesn't work. but if I rename the example_006-old.php to example_006.php it works, but only on that file.